# How can I let music play over several scenes without the music restarting every scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I am very new to Unity and C# and I have a problem with my Audio. The music plays from the beginning everytime i load a scene. How can I let the music play over several scenes without the music restarting?(Sorry for the bad english)
The code I am using is a simple code to adjust the music volume via slider and save the volume across multiple scenes.
I am using the unity 2018.3.14f1 version.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class Volumemultiplelevel : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioMixer mixer;


    void Start()
    {
        SetLevel(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("MusicVol"));
    }

    public void SetLevel(float sliderValue)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("MusicVol", sliderValue);
        mixer.SetFloat("MusicVol", Mathf.Log10(sliderValue) * 20);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new gameobject with a script and the audio source.
The script has to check if it isn't already playing (you can do that with some static bool) and play.

This will make your gameobject (with the audiosource) not get deleted `DontDestroyOnLoad(musicPlayer)`

Put the gameobject in the starting (menu) scene